# How to visit a URL with Ruby via http and read the output?

Tags: ruby, http

So far I have been able to stitch this together :)

```
 begin
  open("http://www.somemain.com/" + path + "/" + blah)
 rescue OpenURI::HTTPError
   @failure += painting.permalink
 else
   @success += painting.permalink
 end
```

But how do I read the output of the service that I would be calling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open-URI extends `open`, so you'll get a type of IO stream returned:

```
open('http://www.example.com') #=> #<StringIO:0x00000100977420>
```

You have to read that to get content:

```
open('http://www.example.com').read[0 .. 10] #=> "<!DOCTYPE h"
```

A lot of times a method will let you pass different types as a parameter. They check to see what it is and either use the contents directly, in the case of a string, or read the handle if it's a stream.

For HTML and XML, such as RSS feeds, we'll typically pass the handle to a parser and let it grab the content, parse it, and return an object suitable for searching further:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.example.com'))
doc.class #=> Nokogiri::HTML::Document
doc.to_html[0 .. 10] #=> "<!DOCTYPE h"
doc.at('h1').text #=> "Example Domains"
```

Comment: While this is true, Open-URI overrides Kernel#open, which is usually used for files. If not used **very** carefully when in combination with user input, this might lead to attackers being able to read contents of your file system. `open(params[:uri])`, `localhost:3000/?uri=/etc/passwd` and so on.

Added to this very old response because it still shows up high up in search results :)

Answer (score 6):

```
doc = open("http://etc..")
content = doc.read
```

More often people want to be able to parse the returned document, for this use something like [hpricot](http://github.com/hpricot/hpricot) or [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you want to do this yourself for the hell of it or not but if you don't.. [Mecanize](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize/) is a really nice gem for doing this.

It will visit the page you want and automatically wrap the page with nokogiri so that you can access it's elements with css selectors such as "div#header h1". Ryan Bates has a [video tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/191-mechanize) on it which will teach you everything you need to know to use it.

Basically you can just

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get("http://www.google.com")
agent.page.at("some css selector").text
```

It's that simple.